# Musical softwares can't open or has an error in the beginning

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I have recently installed the latest Ubuntu studio on my computer.

I have tried to open Ardour and some musical software but Nothing Is running well.

Do i have a specific configuration?

Thanks in Advance,

Have a good day

Comment: If i remembered well , the synthethizer can't open and i have an error .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up JACK - it's the central part of Studio

[Connecting_a_Sound_Card_With_JACK_and_Patchage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook/GettingStarted#Connecting_a_Sound_Card_With_JACK_and_Patchage)
from:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook

some input on Jack and Carla:
https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/ubuntu-studio-20-10-audio-setup-tutorial/

Hope these can help to get you started...

there is also a lot of stuff (and a community) on here:
https://linuxmusicians.com/
and Ardour has it's own Forum here:
https://discourse.ardour.org/

Comment: Thanks i Will take a look :)